# A datatable as the full-featured form element

Tags: javascript, forms, datatable, selection, webix

The idea I'm trying to achieve is to embed the datatable into the form.

For now, the form acts as a container. So far there are no any issues, but the `name` property for the datatable if ignored. The datatable not belongs to the form `elements`. AFAICS the following configuration is pretty common:

```
{
  view:"form",
  elements:[
    { view:"text", name:"inp1", value:"Test input" },    
    { view:"datatable", name:"formDT", autoConfig:true, data:grid_data }
  ]
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/7b7a8f2e

But if in the `dataForm.elements` I see only inputs.

Ideally, I want to get and set the datatable selection through the form's `setValues` and `getValues` methods. Or do I need to write my own method to gather the data from the inputs and the datatable separately? Has anyone faced such task before? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a custom component draft inherit datatable but support getValue setValue in order to act as a form input :

```
webix.protoUI({
  name: "datatableInput",
  defaults: {
  },

  $init: function(config) {

  },

  // Define component value (used by form setValues)
  setValue: function(value) {
    console.log('setValue');
    this.clearSelection();
    if (value) this.select(value);
  },
  // Get component value (used by form getValues)
  getValue: function() {
    console.log('getValue');
    var item = this.getSelectedItem();
    if (item) return item.id;
  }

}, webix.ui.datatable);
```

Updated snippet :

http://webix.com/snippet/f952f35e